# Code blocks aren't tall enough

Tags: bug, design

The CSS styling for code blocks isn't tall enough, and causes issues on single line code blocks, for example:

```
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
```

This gives me a horizontal scroll bar that hides the contents of the last line. Sometimes it fades away on its own, and other times it doesn't.

I would recommend adding padding to `<pre>` tags in post content of at least `10px` to correct this

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I see the issue. Windows, Chrome 59, the code block looks fine to me, nothing is getting cut off or terminated early.

Comment: here it shows but the scrollbar fades in over the top of the content

Comment: May be best to add in browser and other specs. I don't have this issue on windows because of the block scroll bar -> http://i.imgur.com/yAHFtA3.jpg

Comment: Can't find anyone who had the same problem. Does this happen on other SE sites as well? Do you have an updated browser?

Comment: Chrome stable MacOS, both latest public releases

Comment: Windows 7 + Firefox Developers here, [no issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUbPc.jpg). But since it's a mac, it thinks different, and renders different.

Comment: to replicate on a mac in Chrome, scroll to show the scrollbar, then mouse over it. Once you've moused over it the scrollbar remains permanently and can't be dismissed